# Converting an array of objects in to a single object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Have an array which contains a no of json .

```
[{linkValue:"value1"},{linkValue:"value2"},{linkValue:"value3"},{linkValue:"value4"},{linkValue:"value5"}]
```

Note that each Json have same key . I want to convert this array into a single json like

```
{linkValue1:"value1",linkValue2:"value2",linkValue3:"value3",linkValue4:"value4",linkValue5:"value5"}
```

one thing i also need to know . my array is also inside a json how i get this arry from that json ?

My initial json is

```
{name:"value",age:"value",linkValue:[[{linkValue:"value1"},{linkValue:"value2"},{linkValue:"value3"},{linkValue:"value4"},{linkValue:"value5"}]
]}
```

I'm expcting my final json look like :

```
{name:"value",age:"value",linkValue1:"value1",linkValue2:"value2",linkValue3:"value3",linkValue4:"value4",linkValue5:"value5"}
```

can anyone please help me

Comment: i want to convert it into a json

Comment: JSON is a data exchanging format, this has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control) and add properties to an empty object:

```
let source = {name:"value",age:"value",linkValue:[[{linkValue:"value1"},{linkValue:"value2"},{linkValue:"value3"},{linkValue:"value4"},{linkValue:"value5"}]]};

// Copy the array in a variable
let yourArray = source.linkValue[0];

// Delete the original array in the source object 
delete source.linkValue;

yourArray.forEach((item, index) => {
    source["linkValue" + (index + 1)] = item.linkValue
});

console.log(source); // Should have what you want
```

Comment: Insted forEach you could use reduce.

Comment: @PiotrPasieka why don't you provide it as an answer then? :-)

Comment: one thing i also need to know . i forget it to include in ma question . my array is inside an json object how i get that array .

Comment: @Ajmalsha That depends entirely on your JSON structure.

Comment: @PiotrPasieka Its working can you please give a suggestion for how i get my final result

Answer (score 0):

```
[{linkValue:"value1"},{linkValue:"value2"},{linkValue:"value3"},{linkValue:"value4"},{linkValue:"value5"}]
```

This is javascript Array contains multiple javascript object.

```
{linkValue1:"value1",linkValue2:"value2",linkValue3:"value3",linkValue4:"value4",linkValue5:"value5"}
```

If you need structure like this,Then define a single javascript object and add linkvalue1,linkvalue2 etc. as a member of that object and then add it to  javascript Array.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with reduce

```
// HELPER FUNCTIONS

// pick properties from object with default value
function pick (props, sourceObj, defaultValue) {
  return props.reduce(
    (obj, prop) =>
      Object.assign(obj, { [prop]: sourceObj[prop] || defaultValue }),
    {}
  )
}

// get property value or default
function propOr (propName, obj, defaultValue) {
  return obj[propName] || defaultValue
}

// flatten nested array
function flattern (nestedArray) {
  return nestedArray.reduce((flat, innerArray) => flat.concat(innerArray), [])
}

// LINKS BUILDER based on REDUCE
function buildLinks (linksArray) {
  return linksArray.reduce((accumulator, item, index) => {
    accumulator['linkValue' + (index + 1)] = item.linkValue
    return accumulator
  }, {})
}


// TRANSFORMATION FUNCTION - takes json and produce required output
function transform(json) {
  return Object.assign(
    {}, 
    pick(['name', 'age'], json, null), 
    buildLinks(flattern(propOr('linkValue', json, [])))
  )
}

// EXECUTION
const result = transform(source)
```

PS> You can use libraries like Lodash or Ramda and replace helper functions defined by me with ones from library

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce API,

```
let targetObj = srcArr.reduce((accumulator, value, index)=>{
   accumulator['linkValue'+(index+1)] = value.linkValue;
   return accumulator;
}, {});
```

Comment: Check @PiotrPasieka's answer. Don't you think it's a bit.. the same?

Comment: what is the difference between this two

Comment: i get the value like this {linkValue1: undefined, linkValue2: undefined}

Comment: I just cross checked my solution and it is returning me correct object,   { linkValue1: 'value1',
  linkValue2: 'value2',
  linkValue3: 'value3',
  linkValue4: 'value4',
  linkValue5: 'value5' }

Comment: Ok its working fine .  can you please give a suggestion for how i get my final result

Comment: You should get the single object after reducing the array. If you are looking for anything else as a final result let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
myObj.linkValue = myObj.linkValue.map((obj, index) => ({ [`linkValue${index + 1}`]: obj.linkValue }))
```